# What kind of clothes should I use at Egypt and Jordan during the daylight

Tags: egypt, jordan, deserts

I'm going to Egypt and Jordan in April. I'm trying to understand what is the best combination of clothes my wife and I should be used there.

We are occidentals. During our summer in Sydney, Australia we have been wearing shorts, t-shirts or not and most of the time hats.

I don't know if the best practice is wearing light clothes with long sleeves or just a sunscreen I am ok against the strong sun of the region.

**Update**

cities:

- Cairo
- Aswan
- Luxor
- Amman
- Jerash

Comment: Can you give us an idea of where you'll be traveling to? Especially in Jordan this can make a difference in what to expect - as a general rule though Jordan will be milder than Egypt, but neither will be too extreme - as you are not going there during the peak summer months.

Comment: This is two separate questions and should be asked as such.

Comment: Where in Egypt are you going, and are you bothered about things like avoiding funny looks, looking less obviously like a tourist, etc? (if you're just going to resorts in Sharm etc don't bother, wear anything, but if you're going to say downtown Cairo covering arms and legs does help) Also see [What kind of clothes and footwear are ideal to visit Egypt?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/what-kind-of-clothes-and-footwear-are-ideal-to-visit-egypt?rq=1) which might cover some of this question